# how to retain a input String while refreshing a page in Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I could  not able to retain the provided value in an input element after refreshing the page in Selenium webdriver .

But the same scenario works while testing it manually .

Is there anyway where we can retain the input string even after refreshing the page ?

Comment: post some code.
Did value of element is changing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try pressing `Tab Key on the Edit Box` after entering the value in the edit box.